# C Array Linked List, assigning an array linked list to another

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, variable-assignment

I'm trying to write a simple dictionary with an array of linked list but I keep losing data after calling the display function.

Here's my structure definition

```
typedef struct node{
    int elem;
    struct node *next;
}*L;

typedef L Dictionary[10];
```

And here's my display

```
void display(Dictionary A)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("A[%d]: ",i);
        while(A[i]!=NULL){
            printf("%d\t",A[i]->elem);
            A[i] = A[i]->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The solution for this is to make a temporary variable.

I tried

```
Dictionary tempStruct
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
     tempStruct[i] = A[i];
}
```

and it works. But is there any other ways of assigning linked list that is more efficient than this one?

```
tempStruct = A;
```

Doesn't really work, I get `incompatible types node** to Dictionary{*node[10]}`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the loop in your display function to this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("A[%d]: ",i);
    L tmp = A[i];
    while(tmp!=NULL){
        printf("%d\t",tmp->elem);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

There's no need to copy the whole array, a simple temporary pointer navigating through the linked list is enough.

*Side note*: For the copy of the array, you tried to *assign* it with `tempStruct = A;`. There are two reasons this doesn't work:

- Inside your function, `A` doesn't have an array type. C doesn't support passing an *array* to a function. When a function has a parameter with an array type, this is automatically adjusted to a pointer type, and instead of passing an array, a pointer to the array's first element is passed. This effect is often expressed as *the array decays as a pointer*, and it's the reason for your message `incompatible types node** to Dictionary{*node[10]}`.
- Even if `A` **had** an array type, it still wouldn't work because C doesn't allow *assigning* to an array. This is a bit surprising because the same thing would work with a `struct`. I can't think of a good reason why assigning arrays is not allowed in C, you should just remember that you can't. Of course, you can do it manually, and if you don't want to assign every single element, you can use the function [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), declared in `string.h`:

  ```
  int foo[5];
  int bar[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  // instead of foo = bar;
  memcpy(foo, bar, sizeof foo);
  ```

---

Unrelated to your question, but I had a hard time understanding this code. Your `typedef`s are catastrophic for readability. *Never ever* hide a pointer behind a `typedef` -- for understanding the code dealing with a pointer, it's important the pointer is **obvious**. A `typedef` for an array type is at least questionable as well. I would suggest the following code:

```
typedef struct node {
    int elem;
    struct node *next;
} node;
// not strictly necessary, but IMHO, if you want to typedef a struct type,
// it's the least confusing option to name it the same as the struct tag.

#define DICTSIZE 10

void display(node **a) // variable names are often lowercase by convention
{
    // to cope with ANY possible size, you need size_t, int might be too small
    // include stddef.h or stdlib.h to use it. Of course, with 10 elements,
    // int is enough.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < DICTSIZE; ++i) {
        printf("a[%zu]: ", i);
        node *tmp = a[i];

        // now it's obvious tmp is a pointer, so no need to explicitly
        // write the != NULL ... (any pointer that's not NULL evaluates true)
        while (tmp) {
            printf("%d\t", tmp->elem);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Also note how some added spaces greatly improve the readability of the code (so, use them).

---

I would consider your original display function *broken*, because it modified what it displayed. This is not expected behavior for a function that *displays* data. If you want to further improve on your code, you should use `const` to make it explicit that the function shouldn't modify what it receives, so the compiler can catch errors. In the example above, the signature for `display` should better look like this:

```
void display(const node *const *a)
```

The first `const` would make any `struct node` immutable, the second `const` (after the asterisk) makes the pointers in your array immutable. With this, you also have to write

```
    const node *tmp = a[i];
```

because you can't assign a const pointer to a non-const pointer.

Comment: Good sound nuts & bolts programming advise.

Answer (score 0):

In your display function, you modify the entries of the dictionary array with `A[i] = A[i]->next;`, so you corrupt the data structure and lose the data.

You should instead use a local variable to enumerate each list:

```
void display(Dictionary A) {
    struct node *n;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("A[%d]:", i);
        for (n = A[i]; n; n = n->next) {
            printf(" %d", n->elem);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Hiding pointers and arrays behind typedefs is a bad idea, it leads to confusing code for both the reader and the programmer. You should just `typedef struct node node;` and use explicit pointers and arrays.